# BA Executive club avios expiration

Tags: loyalty-programs, british-airways

My last flight with BA was 13-Aug-14.
As I understand I have to have some transaction within 36 months to keep avios - eg till february 2016.
I bought a flight in december 2015 but it is scheduled to november 2016 - is it sufficient to keep avios or not?

And if I buy a seat for this flight, will this transaction be counted or not?

Comment: There are other ways to earn avios to prevent expiry than just flying - see [this dashboard post on Flyertalk for details](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1735854-your-guide-executive-club-attaining-status-earning-avios-2016-a.html#post25948906), or [threads like this one](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1332841-best-cheapest-way-save-expiring-avios-points.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

36 months (three years) after 13 August 2014 is the 13 August 2017.

Therefore your flight in November 2016 will be sufficient to keep your account active.

You do need to take the flight yourself. It won't count if you don't take the flight.

Comment: I see my mistake now - I mixed up days and years: 36 hours is 1,5 days, 36 months is 3 years.